# 2-dimensional vector bundles on projective 3-space

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $V,V'\subset T\mathbf{CP}^3$ be *smooth* (real) 2-dimensional subbundles of the tangent bundle of complex projective 3-space. Suppose that $V$ and $V'$ are isomorphic as topological vector bundles, i.e. there exists a continuous vector bundle isomorphism between $V$ and $V'$.

Are $V$ and $V'$ necessarily isomorphic as smooth vector bundles (i.e. does there exist a smooth map $V\to V'$ which induces a linear isomorphism on the fibers)?

I am aware of a classification of complex vector bundles over projective spaces, but couldn't find anything on real smooth vector bundles. I also think that the fact that both are subbundles of the tangent bundle should make this easy, but I don't know how to use that condition.

Comment: Whenever you have two smooth vector bundles of rank $k$ over the same base manifold, say $E,E'\to M,$ you have their homomorphism bundle, $hom(E,E')\to M,$ which is also a smooth vector bundle. This $hom$ bundle has the subbundle $iso(E,E')$ which is a smooth fiber bundle with fiber $GL_k(\mathbb{R})$. An isomorphism between $E$ and $E'$ is nothing more than a section of $iso(E,E')$. So, your question boils down to the following: Let $P\to M$ be a smooth fiber bundle which admits a *continuous* global section. Does this bundle necessarily admit a smooth global section?

Comment: (And the answer to Amitai's comment is *yes*; it is a version of the standard smooth approximation theorems, adapted to sections of fiber bundles.)

Comment: I conclude from your comments that smooth two vector bundles of the same rank over a compact manifold which are isomorphic as topological vector bundles are also isomorphic as smooth vector bundles. In particular, $V$ and $V'$ above are isomorphic as smooth vector bundles. Is this correct?

Comment: @MikeMiller: Could you please point me towards a reference for the approximation theorems you are referring to? Thanks.

Comment: Hirsch's book on differential topology is a great place to see the proof in the non-fiber bundle case; I think he states the fiber bundle case as an exercise (but I don't remember well). One version of the idea is essentially to use convolution with a small bump function, which takes a continuous function and spits out a nearby smooth function. The hard part is to make this precise when the domain and codomain are not both Euclidean space!

Comment: @srp You are correct in your conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I found a nice exposition of the Whitney approximation theorem for maps between smooth manifolds in John Lee's smooth manifolds book (Theorem 6.26). To apply this theorem, the total space of the $hom$ bundle would need to be a smooth manifold. Is this the case? Where could I read more about $hom$ bundles?

Comment: @srp The total space of the $hom$ bundle is indeed a smooth manifold. In fact, the total space of any *smooth* fiber bundle is a smooth manifold.